# Subjective edits

Tags: discussion

I'm a new user so I'd rather ask here before changing anything...

An answer I posted yesterday, which included a link to a Google translation of an article in Spanish, was edited to make the following changes:

- Remove a "Google-translated article" warning note that I included.
- Remove a ":-)" smiley.

The edit summary was ["formatting"](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/14995/revisions) (second edit).

Now, as I said I'm new to the site and maybe I haven't grasped the style yet, but I find this edit highly subjective and rather unnecessary... except for the reputation points / badges the editing user may have gotten for it.

So I wanted to ask: **are those edits in line with some general policy for the site**, and should I keep from including similar notes or smileys in future answers?

Comment: Welcome, @walen. In our [help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), it states "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."  Without any other context, I would agree with this statement. I have no problem with smiley faces, because it makes users inviting. The only warning I can see there is to not dive into discussion (unless you're in chat) and perhaps the smiley face promotes that? That's a stretch I know...but I see "thank you" and the like removed on SO during editing.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have removed the "Google-translated article" warning, but it also wasn't necessarily clear that's what you were referring to. Said warning wasn't after the link, but after the statement you made, which may have caused confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ, I'll probably rollback the edit and move the warning closer to the link.

Comment: Or you could remove the smiley and replace the warning as a separate new edit, since both of those are useful things to do.